# Need to split one Columns data into different columns in Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a Csv file which has merged columns in it and pandas dataframe is showing it in same way. need to split column as required out put

Csv Sample

##### my current input from csv file is:

```
"Date InformationIdNo.","Date out","Dr.","Cr."
"01 FEB Mart Purchase MATRSC203255H","30 DEC 21","-3,535.61","0","250 - PQRT14225","","",""
"01 FEB Cash Sales CCTR220307AXCDV","30 DEC 21","-34.33","0","20000 - DEFG12","","",""
"01 FEB TransferFT22032FQWE3","01 FEB 21","0","7,436.93","","","",""
```

also need to Index-1 with information column of 0th index

##### Required output needed :

```
|   |  Date     |  Information                  | IdNo.           | Date out  | Dr.       | Cr.       | Balance    |
|---|-----------|-------------------------------|-----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|------------|
| 0 | 01 FEB 21 | Mart Purchase 250 - PQRT14225 |  MATRSC203255H  | 30 DEC 21 | -3,535.61 |  0        | -3,978.61  |
| 1 | 01 FEB 21 | Cash Sales 20000 - DEFG1220   |  MATRSC203255H  | 30 DEC 21 | -34.33    |  0        | -3,944.29  |
| 2 | 01 FEB 21 | Transfer                      |  FT22032FQWE3   | 01 FEB 21 | 0         |  7,426.93 |  3,482.65  |
```

[Input CSV file Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRhzN.png)

[CSV file when opened in notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fdon.png)

[Output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny4ej.png)

Comment: your format is ambiguous, this doesn't look like a csv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could specify a delimiter to `read_csv` so that instead of "comma separated" the values will be assumed to be "blank-separated"

Comment: @mozway I am getting data in Csv format extracted from pdf

Comment: @rammelmueller not worked separator not worked for me in this case

Comment: It's hard to say more without seeing the input. Can you please provide a line from the CSV?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because doesn't provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @rammelmueller I am adding the some rows of the csv file in question

Comment: Open csv with notepad and screenshot the image in your question

Comment: please open your csv file in any text redactor (but not in excel) like notepad or notepad++, copy and paste the content of your file to the post as text.

Comment: @GreyMurav I have attached the image, please view

Comment: @pyaj I have attached the image, please view

Comment: @Mohit, please find the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the idea of the code below is quite clear. First we need to correct data in the csv file to valid csv (comma separated value) format. After that we can create dataframe.

**'data.csv' file content**

```
"Date InformationIdNo."," Date out ","Dr."," Cr."
"01 FEB 21 Mart Purchase MATRSC203255H","30 DEC 21","-3,535.61","0"
"250 - PQRT14225","","",""
"01 FEB 21 Cash Sales CCTR220307AXCDV","30 DEC 21","-34.33","0"
"20000 - DEFG12","","",""
"01 FEB 21 TransferFT22032FQWE3"," 01 FEB 21","0","7,426.93"
"","","",""
"","","",""
"","","",""
"","","",""
"","","",""
```

**Possible (quick) solution is the following:**

```
#pip install pandas

import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open("data.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    raw_data = file.read()
    
# convert txt to valid csv (comma separated values) format
raw_data = raw_data.replace(' - ', '-')
raw_data = raw_data.replace('Date InformationIdNo.', 'Date","Information","IdNo.')
raw_data = raw_data.replace('" Cr."', '"Cr","Information_add"')
raw_data = re.sub('(\d{2} [A-Z]{3} \d{2})', r'\1","', raw_data)
raw_data = re.sub('\n"([A-Z0-9-]+)","","",""\n', r',"\1"\n', raw_data)
raw_data = re.sub(r',""{2,}', '', raw_data)
raw_data = re.sub('([A-Z0-9]{3,}",")', r'","\1","', raw_data)
raw_data = re.sub(',""+', r'', raw_data)
raw_data = re.sub('\n""+', r'', raw_data)

# # create dataframe and replace NaN with ""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_data), sep=",")
df.fillna("", inplace=True)

# merge columns and drop temporary column
df['Information'] = df['Information'] + df['Information_add']
df.drop(['Information_add'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# cleanup column headers
df.columns = [name.strip() for name in df.columns]

# convert date to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.title().str.strip(), format="%d %b %y", dayfirst=True)
df['Date out'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date out'].str.title().str.strip(), format="%d %b %y", dayfirst=True)

df
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am using pd.read_csv to read the csv file, I have attached the screenshot of csv file, also I will try your code.

Comment: please provide the content of your `csv` file as a text

Comment: I have only sample csv file, Also I have attached the screenshot of the sample file.

Comment: I mean please open your csv file in any text redactor (but not in excel) like notepad or notepad++, copy and paste the content of your file to the post as text.